# Preventing login with Laravel's Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to prevent the user from logging in under some conditions.

My idea is to perform some additional checks after using Laravel's Auth system.
As for the login / register and recover password systems, everything works fine. But I can't seem to be able to log out the user and show a custom error in the login page.

All I want to do is to show a custom "your account was suspended" message under the "email address" field, after verifying if the user was suspended or not.

[image]

My code (HomeController), as well as some of my solutions:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        // After Laravel logs the user through its authentication system
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!isset($user)) {
            return redirect('/');

        } else {    
            // we perform some checks of our own
            if ($user->suspended != 0) { // suspended by an administrator
                $error = trans('errors_login.SUSPENDED_BY_ADMIN');

               // return redirect()->route('logout', array('error_msg' => $error));

               // return redirect()->route('logout')->withErrors('email','There was an error'); // trying to replace the "email" error


               Auth::logout();

               $error = ['loginError'=> trans('errors_login.SUSPENDED_BY_ADMIN')];
               return view('auth.login', $error);


            }
        }
...
```

Just to clarify what the "logout" route is:

```
Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

I'm using Laravel's generated login view:

```
...

<div class="form-group row">
<label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">E-Mail Address</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

    @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

Nothing seems to work.
I'm fairly new to Laravel, so I must be missing something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel's default login controller (`App\Http\Controller\Auth\LoginController`) uses a trait called `AuthenticatesUsers` under the hood.

So, whenever a user is authenticated, it calls an `authenticated()` method prior to sending the login response back, which means, you could probably do something like this.

In `App\Http\Controller\Auth\LoginController` add a new `authenticated()` method which overrides `AuthenticatesUsers::authenticated()`.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->suspended) {
        Auth::logout();

        return back()
            ->with('loginError', trans('errors_login.SUSPENDED_BY_ADMIN'));
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: Excellent, very elegant solution. Thanks. How do you know which methods you can override in LoginController? Is there a doc I may follow? Note: I ended up using ->withErrors() instead of ->with(). Like this: return back()->withErrors(array('loginError' => trans('errors_login.SUSPENDED_BY_ADMIN')));

Comment: You're welcome. I usually have [Laravel's API](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/index.html) bookmarked for reference :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this also :

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)//this will get triggered if the method above (attemptLogin(Request $request))  returns false.
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
    ];
    $valid = Auth::attempt($credentials);

    if ($valid == false) { //if user credentials are incorrect
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];
         Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    } else { // //if user credentials are correct check additional conditions
        $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
        if ($user->locked == 1) {
            $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.locked')];
            Auth::logout();
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [trans('auth.locked')],
            ]);
        } else {
            $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.notactivated')];
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors($errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if is good enough, but it also working.